# why did Elisha lay on the boy two times in order to raise him from the dead in 2 Kings 4:35

Tags: kings

In second kings, chapter 4 Elisha went to the son of the Shunammite woman to raise him from the dead after Gehazi’s attempt had failed. It says that Elisha got on the bed and stretched out upon him once more in verse 35 and then he sneezed seven times and opened his eyes. Why was a second time needed? Between times he had got up, turned away and walked back-and-forth in the room. Wondering what had been occurring during that time if anything other than prayer. Wondering also if the two times were representative of Christ, raising us physically, and then also spiritually. His identification with us in both ways?

Comment: The staff did not raise the child. The prophet, alone, did not raise the child. Then the prophet walked to and fro _in the house_. Then . . ..  then, the third time, was the child raised from the dead. The House, and the third. Significance. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid interpreting it metaphorically.

In 1 Kings 4:34, the account describes Elisha laid on the boy mouth to mouth, eyes to eyes, hands to hands, in order to warm up the boy. It should be noted that Elisha did not fully lie down on the boy. Instead, he supported his own weight to ensure that the boy could breathe freely. This act of care might have left Elisha physically exhausted, prompting the need for rest.